# match any set of fields in the database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.1.3 for my application. 
I have the following condition to match:

**"Find those records that matches with any 3 fields from the 4 given fields."**

The 4 fields are `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `father_name`. I want to find those records which matches with any 3 of above given 4 fields.

What would be the sql query to do it? And if possible, how I can do it in CakePHP using Models. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried anything in advance..?

Comment: The simplest way I did it to match each combination of fields in the database. I am trying to find an optimal solution.

Comment: when they are empty, do those fields contain NULL?

Comment: Yes, the field contains null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your question,you're main problem seems to be performance. To improve performance you have to decrease the number of `if(value1==value2)`

```
   array('OR'=>array(
    array( "AND" => array (
        "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
        "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
        "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
    ),
    array( "AND" => array (
        "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
        "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
        "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
    ),
    array( "AND" => array (
        "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
        "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
        "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
    ),
    array( "AND" => array (
        "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
        "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
        "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
    ),

   )
```

This solution makes 12n tests.

I propose your make a subquery:

-the first one taking the records matching any of the four fields

-then you run the above query on the returned results

If there is a great variability in names, which seems credible, the first query will remove much of the data, bringing your queries to a little more than 4n tests.

If the data is highly homogeneous (everyone has the same name), you could look for 1 field, then 2, then 3.

EDIT with another solution:

I suppose that 'dob' stands for date of birth. It seems logical that among 150000 people the Dot will be evenly distributed.

So I make a test to see if `Model.dot==value`. Then we have two possibilities:

It returns true: we have to check on the three other fields to see if  at least 2 fits

It returns false: we have to check if if the remaining three exactly fit.

The first sub-set will be small so it doesn't matter performance-wise. The second will require only 4 test per record, instead of 12 as it was the case before.

Comment: I can't take this situation into consideration. As it is very sensitive data and also a huge possibility of heterogeneity.

Comment: uhm... What does the 'dob' field stands for?

Comment: date of birth? If so you could test first dob. Then the rest. It will bring you to 4n tests too.

Comment: Thanks ALS, but I am getting confused what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

I think the condition set could be :

```
    array('OR'=>array(
        array( "AND" => array (
            "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
            "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
            "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
        ),
        array( "AND" => array (
            "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
            "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
            "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
        ),
        array( "AND" => array (
            "Model.DOB" =>$val3 ,
            "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
            "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
        ),
        array( "AND" => array (
            "Model.father_name" =>$val4 ,
            "Model.first_name" =>$val1 ,
            "Model.last_name" =>$val2 ,
        ),

)
```

Comment: +1. But I did it in the same manner. I was expecting any other optimal solution using any kind of regular expr. or switch case something like as the current query is taking  10.2350 seconds to find the records from 152053 users. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$conditions = array('OR'=>array($your_input=>array('first_name', 'last_name', 'dob'),
                                    $your_input=>array('first_name', 'last_name', 'father_name'),
                                    $your_input=>array( 'last_name', 'dob', 'father_name'),
                                    ));
    $result = $this->Model->find('All',array('fields'=>'required_field','conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Comment: 1 vote up. But I think there is some problem with the syntax you written.